# there are 300 cities such that for every 4 cities you can get from one to other without passing other 296 cities

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

The country has 300 cities, some pairs of cities are connected by roads.  It turned out that for any four cities from any city of this four you can get to any other city of this four without passing through the remaining 296 cities.  At what is the largest n in the country, it is possible to choose n cities so that any two selected cities are connected by road?

This is definitely a graph problem. I've solved problems like this with  anti-edges
(like if two vertices are not connected then they are connected with anti-edges) But now it doesn't help

Comment: What else have you tried? You seem to mention graph complementation, but couldn't get any where with it. To help get you started, here is what your problem says in more graph-theoretic terms: Given is a graph $G$ of order $300$ in which the subgraph induced by any $4$ vertices is connected. The problem is to determine the largest $n$ for which we are guaranteed the existence of the subgraph $K_n \subseteq G$, i.e. the clique on $n$ vertices or the graph with $n$ vetices and all possible edges present.

Comment: This question is poorly worded. Do you mean the minimum number of roads needed? Certainly a country where every two cities have a road between them will do.

Comment: @Mike: We don’t get to decide which pairs of cities have direct connections by road; all we know is that there are enough roads so that if we think of the cities as vertices and the roads between them as edges, any subgraph induced by $4$ vertices is connected. That much is clear. The actual question has been somewhat awkwardly translated from the source language, but my interpretation is the same as **Paralyzed_by_Time**’s.

Comment: Is this some contest problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph whose vertices are the cities and the vertices are adjacent iff they are *not* connected by a road. Then the question is about the size of a largest independent set of vertices of $G$.

If $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree at least three then $v$ together with its three neighbors constitute a set of four cities violating the question condition. Thus each vertex of $G$ has degree at most two. It easily follows that $G$ is a union of vertex-disjoint cycles or paths. Moreover, the question condition implies that $G$ has no cycles of length four.

Conversely, if $H$ is any graph which is a union of vertex-disjoint cycles (of length distinct from four) or paths then in the complement of $H$ any induced four-vertex subgraph $F$ is connected. Indeed, if the vertices of $F$ do not belong to one connected component of $H$, then $F$ contains a copy of a complete $k$-partite subgraph for $k\ge 2$ (that is, $K_{1,3}$, $K_{2,2}$, $K_{2,1,1}$ or $K_{1,1,1,1}$), so it is connected. If the vertices of $F$ belong to one connected component of $H$ then it easy to see that $F$ contains a copy of a path with four vertices, so it is connected.

Since a cycle (path) with $k$ vertices contains an independent set of size $\lfloor k/2\rfloor$ ($\lceil k/2\rceil$), which is at least $k/3$, $G$ has an independent set of size at least $300/3=100$ and this minimum is attained when $G$ is a union of vertex-disjoint triangles.

Comment: Very nice! $\;$